# How to filter a text file content using another text file as sample

Tags: bash, command-line

I have two text files, one with the following content:

```
Brazil
China
USA
```

And another file with the following content:

```
Brazil  8   9   5   2
China   1   2   2   1
France  7   4   1   2
Italy   0   1   2   3
Spain   5   4   6   8
UK      8   5   4   1
USA     1   2   3   4
```

I would like to use some command that compares both files and returns

```
Brazil  8   9   5   2
China   1   2   2   1
USA     1   2   3   4
```

The command comm doesn't seem to work in cases like this. How could I solve it?

Edit: although this question is marked as duplicated, the solutions for the other question are not the same presented here.

Comment: `comm` compares files line by line. That doesn't sound at all like what you want. Look at `grep` and check the `-f` option. It's very simple. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have nation names in file `1` and names and numbers in file `2` then

```
grep -wFf 1 2
```

should do the trick.

Comment: some systems also have an equivalent `fgrep -f 1 2`. Good luck to all.